# Web app performanace on iPhone Vs Android

Tags: iphone, android, ios, web-applications, safari

It is generally said/accepted that a native app would always have a better/smooth performance compared to a web app..

Is this statement true across all the platforms (iPhone/Android/BB,etc) ? Does this not apply correctly for an iPhone i.e. to say that for iPhone web app, it utlizies some kind of GPU acceleration or something (though not very sure how that works) and hence the performance gap is not much ?

Could you please elaborate on the same. Essentially I wanted to understand if I have a high performance app (which would include lots of animation/high memory usage,etc), is it better to have that as a native app OR if the target audience is only iPhone, even a web app would perform good..Having said that, will Android also reduce the performance gap between native and web in the near future?

Also any examples of really high performance web sites which I can try viewing on iPhone/Android to compare the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a big question there :)

Web apps are all the hype because you don't need to learn Android or obj c so people with skills like web design and scripting can make apps fairly easily. The problem with web apps I find is that you have to be very conscious of how everything works as everything has to render every time.

I've found some web apps crash when you do too much too quickly, even with HTML 5 there's some bugs. On iPhone and Android devices if your app was say a shopping app you could pre render results for a query and only show them when required.

Another problem with web apps is connectivity. I know some people say the internet is everywhere but what if you;re abroad and your carrier charges roaming for bandwidth? I know the ones in Ireland used to charge 10e a meg to uses the internet. Fair enough if the app whether native or web required a connection both will suffer

As for the cpu and gpu performanance that will mostly rely on the model you're using. The iPhone models speak for themselves but there's sooooo many Android phones with different processors it's hard to benchmark. Also take into account internet connectivity..... a lot of factors

With both platforms there are endless pros and cons. I find web apps are quick and easy but can fall short of the nice functionality in Android and iOS APIs. On the other hand the Android and iOS APIs can be head wrecking and cause weeks of headaches